# how to close an owned Form2, when Form1 is the owner

Tags: .net, visual-studio, methods, owner

i have form1, and i call form2 by using show(this) in form1.

I have in Form1

private: Form2^ form2;

```
private: Methode1(....  )
 {
  form2=gcnew Form2^();
  form2->show(this);

 };
```

my Question is: 
how can i close the owned Form (Form2).

Comment: When do you want to close it? Don't you have a button in form2 which says "Close" or similar?

Comment: form2->Close() is the obvious answer.  Surely you have a better question?

Comment: but form2->Close() dosen't work in form2.h because the owner of form2 is form1?

Comment: If you are **IN** Form2, then can't you just close it with `this->Close()`?

Comment: Mr Idle_Mind, what do you suggest to close form2 by calling method form2_closed()?